# (How) is it possible to have polymorphic values in a `dependent-map` GADT?

Tags: haskell, gadt, reflex

Anyone knows how/if it's possible to extend the `Foo` GADT in [this code](https://github.com/mokus0/dependent-map/pull/16#issuecomment-384380287):

```
{-# language GADTs #-}
{-# language DeriveGeneric #-}
{-# language DeriveAnyClass #-}
{-# language TemplateHaskell #-}
{-# language StandaloneDeriving #-}

import Prelude                  (Int, String, print, ($))
import Data.GADT.Show           ()
import Data.GADT.Compare        ()
import Data.Dependent.Map       (DMap, fromList, (!))
import Data.Dependent.Sum       ((==>))
import Data.GADT.Compare.TH     (deriveGEq, deriveGCompare)
import Data.Functor.Identity    (Identity)

data Foo a where
  AnInt   :: Foo Int
  AString :: Foo String

deriveGEq      ''Foo
deriveGCompare ''Foo

dmap1 :: DMap Foo Identity
dmap1 = fromList [AnInt ==> 1, AString ==> "bar"]

main = do
  print $ dmap1 ! AnInt
  print $ dmap1 ! AString

  -- Prints:
  -- Identity 1
  -- Identity "bar"
```

with

```
  ANum :: Num n => Foo n
```

(or something similar) to allow for polymorphic values in a [`dependent-map`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/dependent-map)?

When I try, I get a type error like this:

```
exp-dep-map.hs:20:1: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘a’ with ‘b’
      ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          geq :: forall a b. Foo a -> Foo b -> Maybe (a := b)
        at exp-dep-map.hs:20:1-20
      ‘b’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          geq :: forall a b. Foo a -> Foo b -> Maybe (a := b)
        at exp-dep-map.hs:20:1-20
      Expected type: Maybe (a := b)
        Actual type: Maybe (a :~: a)
    • In a stmt of a 'do' block: return Refl
      In the expression: do return Refl
      In an equation for ‘geq’: geq ANum ANum = do return Refl
    • Relevant bindings include
        geq :: Foo a -> Foo b -> Maybe (a := b)
          (bound at exp-dep-map.hs:20:1)
   |
20 | deriveGEq      ''Foo
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

---

Edit: I've continued working on this together with echatav and isovector (GitHub usernames) and we were able to figure this question out further, and we also found that defining `GEq` and `GCompare` instances by hand helps. So thank you, @rampion, your answer also corroborates what we've found.

Although it's much less than ideal to define these manually for large record types. I wonder if the TemplateHaskell generators (`deriveGCompare`, `deriveGEq`) {would need to be,could be} updated to handle polymorphism.

Also, I've found that for my current use-case the pol'ism I'm looking for is actually closer to

```
data Foo n a where
  AnInt :: Foo n Int
  AString :: Foo n String
  ANum :: (Num n, Typeable n, Show n) => Foo n n
```

Hand-defining instances works here too, and again, less than ideal.

```
instance GEq (Foo n) where
  geq AnInt AnInt = return Refl
  geq AString AString = return Refl
  geq ANum ANum = return Refl
  geq _ _ = Nothing

instance GCompare (Foo n) where
  gcompare AnInt AnInt = GEQ
  gcompare AnInt _ = GLT
  gcompare _ AnInt = GGT
  gcompare AString AString = GEQ
  gcompare AString _ = GLT
  gcompare _ AString = GGT
  gcompare (ANum :: Foo n a) (ANum :: Foo n b) = (eqT @a @b) & \case
    Just (Refl :: a :~: b) -> GEQ
    Nothing   -> error "This shouldn't happen"
  gcompare ANum _ = GLT
  gcompare _ ANum = GGT
```

Trying to use TH, (e.g. `deriveGEq ''Foo` or `deriveGEq ''(Foo n)`) I run into kind-issues.

```
exp-dep-map.hs:39:1: error:
    • Expecting one more argument to ‘Foo’
      Expected kind ‘* -> *’, but ‘Foo’ has kind ‘* -> * -> *’
    • In the first argument of ‘GEq’, namely ‘Foo’
      In the instance declaration for ‘GEq Foo’
   |
39 | deriveGEq      ''Foo
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

```
exp-dep-map.hs:40:19: error: parse error on input ‘Foo’
   |
40 | deriveGEq      ''(Foo n)
   |                   ^^^
```

Maybe relevant: https://github.com/mokus0/dependent-sum-template/pull/6

Answer (score 5):

The template  haskell makes it hard to see what's going on, so I suggest you roll your own instances of `GEq` to understand the error better.

Look at [the definition of `GEq`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/dependent-sum-0.4/docs/Data-GADT-Compare.html#t:GEq):

```
class GEq f where
  geq :: f a -> f b -> Maybe (a := b)
```

We don't get any further constraints on `a` or `b`, so we'd need to prove (or disprove) type equality on the GADT's constructors alone.

Which the above `ANum` doesn't give us.

This is fixable, though, if we add another constraint to `ANum` - `Typeable`

```
ANum :: (Num n, Typeable n) => n -> Foo n
```

Now we can use [`eqT`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Data-Typeable.html#v:eqT) to witness type equality

```
geq (ANum _) (ANum _) = eqT
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! In the meantime together with echatav and isovector (GH names) we were able to figure this question out further, and we also found that defining `GEq` and `GCompare` instances by hand helps. Although it's much less than ideal for large record types. I wonder if the TH generator would need to be/could be updated to handle polymorphism.

Comment: Also, I've found that for my current use-case the pol'ism I'm looking for is actually closer to `data Foo n a where AnInt :: Foo n Int; ANum :: (Num n, Typeable n) => Foo n n`. Hand-defining instances works here too, and again, less than ideal. Trying to use TH, (e.g. `deriveGEq ''Foo` or `deriveGEq ''(Foo n)`) I run into kind-issues. Maybe relevant: https://github.com/mokus0/dependent-sum-template/pull/6